# How can I send a custom url screenshot on discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, puppeteer

So, I try to do a command. You need to write '!screenshot" + a custom url. It needs to take that url and take a screenshot of it and send it back to the respective channel. I tried many ways but I cant make it work.

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const cheerio = require("cheerio");
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');


module.exports =  {
  name: 'screenshot',
    description: 'makes a screenshot and sends it back',
    usage: '[command name]',
    cooldown: 5,

  execute(message, args) {
        const data = [];
    //const url = message.client;
    if (message.content.startsWith("!screenshot ")) {
      const url = message.content.substr("!screenshot ".length);
    };
  },
  async run(client, message, args) {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    //const page = await context.newPage();
    //const url = args.join(' ');  // or something similar?
    await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
    

    console.log(await page.content());
    await page.screenshot({path: 'screenshot.png'});

    let screenshot = await page.screenshot(); 
    await browser.close();

    message.channel.send("Screenshot", {files: [screenshot]});
    } 

    
}
```

Comment: What kind of errors happens when you run your code? What exactly is not working? Also, the current code in this question has an undefined variable `url` in its `run` function. Also, what is the difference between `execute` and `run`?

Comment: I doesn't show me any kind of error, it's just empty. It does not send any screenshot in the discord channel also. I dont know the difference, but I will search the solution.

Comment: does the screenshot save?

Comment: I don't think so.